# Transfer to VPS and SEO

Tags: seo, vps, dedicated-hosting

If I have a shared hosting with a dedicated IP address and want to transfer my site to a VPS plan, Is this will affect on my archive on Google or any SEO aspects?

Answer (score 1):

The difference between a dedicated IP address over a shared IP address is minimal if it still exists. You should not see any difference at all.

The exception is where you have chosen a poor web host or are on a server/network that has engaged in bad behaviors.

**Make sure your host is the best/highest quality you can find. The difference in saving a *buck* can really hurt you.**

This is key. Make sure you chose a host with an outstanding reputation in Google's eyes and not be suckered into marketing speak before buying. You can spot check some of the hosts IP addresses in blacklists and do some various searches to see if the hosts systems are engaged in bad behavior before buying.